# Watch the values on the Internal Stack created during Recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memory

I am trying to understand a code snippet involving recursion. It's pre-order traversal of a tree.

```
/* traversing the tree in pre order */
public void printTreeInPreOrder(Node<T> node) {   -- runs in the main method stack
   if (node == null)
    return;
    System.out.println(node.key);
    printTreeInPreOrder(node.left); --- Will create first internal stack
    printTreeInPreOrder(node.right); --- Will create the second internal stack
}
```

What I really want is to watch the values in the internal stack at every step of code execution. Like what values are being pushed & popped from the two internal stacks created in this case.

It really helps in understanding the recursion programs flow.

I researched it found some answers like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));
```

this gives me this in the console.

[image]

Doesn't help much because I already know the flow, I need to see the values in the internal stacks during the flow.

I also read about using the Eclipse debugger 
I enabled the static variables & show references too.

[image]

that gave me this

[image]

Still doesn't help. Way too complicated.

I want something simple like

**Stack 1:** 3 2 1

**Stack 2:** 1

[image]

Possible?

Comment: I used this website while preparing for exams. Check if this helps. https://visualgo.net/en

Comment: IMO the best way to visualize aa algorithm would be to pick a sample input and do a dry on on paper and trace it out which would really help in cementing the basics

Comment: What "two internal stacks" are you talking about? There is a stack. It gets pushed and popped. That's it.

Comment: @rici every recursive call has it's own internal stack. printTreeInPreOrder twice in the method so 2 stacks.

Comment: Each call creates a stack frame on the stack. But there is only one stack and there are a lot more than two calls (unless your tree is very small). If you are talking about the two calls in one execution context of that function, they probably end up using exactly the same memory because the call frames are not active simultaneously.

Comment: Oh, and println is also a function, so there are actually three calls.

Comment: @rici nope if there are n recursive calls in a method there will be n internal stacks. And I am not talking about the number of iterations that a recursive method performs. I am talking about the recursion instances in the code. I've updated the code. plz have a look. And yes there will be one additional method stack but that will already be there even before the flow enters the method. Read http://cryptroix.com/2016/10/10/understanding-multiple-recursion/

Comment: @rici You are right about Each call creates a stack frame on the stack. But I ain't talking about the number of calls. I am talking about the number of instances of recursion in the method.

Comment: @underdog: i think you should find a better guide. That one is way too confusing to be useful.

Comment: @underdog: am I right to assume that your "internal stacks" is just a word for you to describe a model of several snapshots of the stack, where each snapshot is taken when the function `printTreeInOrder` is called?

Comment: @sn42 I went through this article, it's a pretty detailed one. http://cryptroix.com/2016/10/10/understanding-multiple-recursion/  It says if your method has n recursive calls at the compile time, not the runtime; for an instance in a tree traversal we generally have 2 recursive calls in code. printTreeInPreOrder(node.left); printTreeInPreOrder(node.right); 1 for left child & the other for right child. All the stack frames are not in 1 stack but in different stacks. 1st stack all left child recursion values,2nd stack rightval
So we will have 2 internal stacks created. Is the concept incorrect?

Comment: @sn42 I'll try to explain the flow. Before the flow enters the Method "printTreeInPreOrder" It runs in the method stack which has the main function "psvm" as the first element right at the bottom; When the flow enters the method & finds the first recursive call a new stack is created which holds the values for it's recursion & so on. 
What do u think?

Comment: @underdog I think I understand your problem now. The article you mentioned encourages its readers to grab pen and paper and draw a stack for each recursive method invocation. This was done to easily show the input and the output of each recursive method invocation to the reader. But that's it. It's just a way to easily show the variable contents for one full recursive method invocation, but it's just a mental model. There are no internal (or multiple) stacks in the real world, there is just one stack where data is pushed and popped.

Comment: @sn42 Alright, lemme check in the Eclipse debugger the flow & the number of stacks created. Maybe you are right
The code in article too says two stacks [print("This value have been removed from first stack",x)
        hello(x-1)                            
        print("This value have been removed from second stack",x) ]
I guess it's misleading.

Comment: Here is some additional info of the [Java memory model](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html), just to clarify that there are indeed multiple stacks (one per thread), but i didn't mention it because that would make the discussion more complicated

Comment: @sn42 Read the comment by Vijitha Kumara https://coderanch.com/t/469992/java/multiple-recursion-stacks
Says exactly what I was saying earlier. Though I am still researching on multiple recursion... Investigation ongoing

Comment: Just to make it official, read the [Oracle SE7 JVM Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2). Chapter 2.5.2. Java Virtual Machine Stacks is the chapter you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint in eclipse at the `printTreeInOrder()` invocation, start debugging and monitor the value of its `node` parameter.
[image: Eclipse Debugger]
In the debug view you can select the frame you want to check out, the variables only show the variables for the currently selected frame. If you continue the program with `Step Into` (or similar) you can see frames getting added and beeing removed from the stack.